# xcode facebooksdk build issues (null): Symbol(s) not found for architecture i386

Tags: xcode, facebook

Below is an outout of the build issues, I just don't get it, i've added the SDK multiple ways, everyone seems to suggest different ways, is there a right way??! I have xcode latest and facebooksdk latest. I think it's how i'm referencing the sdk but how should I reference it? ANy other ideas?

```
Ld "/Users/stevetaylor/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Late_Trains-bmoirwgxqmfapzbtjqzoklehuvpd/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Late Trains.app/Late Trains" normal i386
cd "/Users/stevetaylor/Desktop/Iphone/Late Trains"
setenv IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 6.1
setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch i386 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.1.sdk -L/Users/stevetaylor/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Late_Trains-bmoirwgxqmfapzbtjqzoklehuvpd/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator "-L/Users/stevetaylor/Desktop/Iphone/Late Trains/../../../Documents/FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.framework/Versions/A" -F/Users/stevetaylor/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Late_Trains-bmoirwgxqmfapzbtjqzoklehuvpd/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator "-F/Users/stevetaylor/Desktop/Iphone/Late Trains/../../../Documents/FacebookSDK" "-F/Users/stevetaylor/Desktop/Iphone/Late Trains" -filelist "/Users/stevetaylor/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Late_Trains-bmoirwgxqmfapzbtjqzoklehuvpd/Build/Intermediates/Late Trains.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Late Trains.build/Objects-normal/i386/Late Trains.LinkFileList" -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -mios-simulator-version-min=6.1 -lsqlite3 -framework FacebookSDK -framework Social -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -framework CoreGraphics -framework Accounts -framework Social -framework AdSupport -o "/Users/stevetaylor/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Late_Trains-bmoirwgxqmfapzbtjqzoklehuvpd/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Late Trains.app/Late Trains"

ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/stevetaylor/Desktop/Iphone/Late Trains/Social.framework/Social, missing required architecture i386 in file /Users/stevetaylor/Desktop/Iphone/Late Trains/Social.framework/Social (2 slices)
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/stevetaylor/Desktop/Iphone/Late Trains/Accounts.framework/Accounts, missing required architecture i386 in file /Users/stevetaylor/Desktop/Iphone/Late Trains/Accounts.framework/Accounts (2 slices)
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/stevetaylor/Desktop/Iphone/Late Trains/AdSupport.framework/AdSupport, missing required architecture i386 in file /Users/stevetaylor/Desktop/Iphone/Late Trains/AdSupport.framework/AdSupport (2 slices)
```

Undefined symbols for architecture i386:

```
 "_ACFacebookAppIdKey", referenced from:
  -[FBSystemAccountStoreAdapter requestAccessToFacebookAccountStore:defaultAudience:isReauthorize:appID:session:handler:] in FacebookSDK(FBSystemAccountStoreAdapter.o)
 "_ACFacebookAudienceEveryone", referenced from:
  -[FBSystemAccountStoreAdapter requestAccessToFacebookAccountStore:defaultAudience:isReauthorize:appID:session:handler:] in FacebookSDK(FBSystemAccountStoreAdapter.o)
 "_ACFacebookAudienceFriends", referenced from:
  -[FBSystemAccountStoreAdapter requestAccessToFacebookAccountStore:defaultAudience:isReauthorize:appID:session:handler:] in FacebookSDK(FBSystemAccountStoreAdapter.o)
 "_ACFacebookAudienceKey", referenced from:
  -[FBSystemAccountStoreAdapter requestAccessToFacebookAccountStore:defaultAudience:isReauthorize:appID:session:handler:] in FacebookSDK(FBSystemAccountStoreAdapter.o)
 "_ACFacebookAudienceOnlyMe", referenced from:
  -[FBSystemAccountStoreAdapter requestAccessToFacebookAccountStore:defaultAudience:isReauthorize:appID:session:handler:] in FacebookSDK(FBSystemAccountStoreAdapter.o)
 "_ACFacebookPermissionsKey", referenced from:
  -[FBSystemAccountStoreAdapter requestAccessToFacebookAccountStore:defaultAudience:isReauthorize:appID:session:handler:] in FacebookSDK(FBSystemAccountStoreAdapter.o)
 "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ACAccountStore", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in FacebookSDK(FBSystemAccountStoreAdapter.o)
 "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ASIdentifierManager", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in FacebookSDK(FBUtility.o)
 "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SLComposeViewController", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in FacebookSDK(FBDialogs.o)
 "_SLServiceTypeFacebook", referenced from:
  +[FBDialogs composeViewControllerWithSession:handler:] in FacebookSDK(FBDialogs.o)
 "_SecRandomCopyBytes", referenced from:
  +[FBCrypto randomBytes:] in FacebookSDK(FBCrypto.o)
  -[FBCrypto encrypt:additionalDataToSign:] in FacebookSDK(FBCrypto.o)
 "_kSecRandomDefault", referenced from:
  +[FBCrypto randomBytes:] in FacebookSDK(FBCrypto.o)
  -[FBCrypto encrypt:additionalDataToSign:] in FacebookSDK(FBCrypto.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: Have you added all the necessary frameworks? Such as Social.framework, Accounts.framework, etc.

Comment: I'm experiencing the exact same error. Haven't been able to figure it out yet.

Comment: Which version of the Facebook SDK are you using? If you're using xcode 5 the latest version of the [Facbeook SDK 3.8](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/change-log-3.x/) adds support for it. That's the issue I was having and upgrading the SDK worked perfectly.